# how to store dialog properties/values under jcr:content node in cq5

Tags: extjs, aem

I copied tags field from /libs/foundation/components/page/tab_basic/items/basic/items/tags into my component dialog. I am able to see the tags populated in drop down and also able to select. I need to store the selected tags in page properties(under jcr:content node). Is there any property required to do the same.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, I have extended compositefield containing TagInputField . Tags to select are populated but not storing the selected tags. (:

Answer (score 1):

Tags are automatically saved in a multi-value String property:

> yourpage->jcr:content->cq:tags

you can check it in crxde light:

```
http://localhost:4502/crx/de/index.jsp
```

If you use the TagInputField xtype for your field in the dialog.xml:

```
<tags jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
      fieldLabel="Tags"
      name="./cq:tags"
      xtype="tags">
</tags>
```

Comment: Ah I see you're trying to do this in a component. Well then it's not automatically saved. But you should be able to access the cq:tags property nontheless

Comment: Yes Mish, I am trying to do this in a component, I able to see the tags populated in the component dialog but not able to save the values in  jcr:content node like page properties.

Comment: Are you using the TagInputField in your dialog? http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.tagging.TagInputField
Or do you manually populate a dropdown field? If so, I would strongly suggest to use the TagInputField if possible.